# WKWebView Not Releasing Memory ios11

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, xcode9, addsubview

Our `iOS11` app displays documents and images that are pre-fetched from a remote database and stored in a local dictionary.

When user selects a document/image name from list of available documents/images, the document/image is displayed in a `UIViewController` using `WKWebView.addSubview()`.  All good and works just as intended.

Problem is that when the display `UIViewController` is popped off the stack, the memory allocated to addSubView is not released. Especially for larger (>10MB) multi-page graphics-intensive documents, the retained memory can become a significant problem.  Thoughts on resolution much appreciated!

```
for view in appDelegate.global.docWebViewDict {
        if view.0 == appDelegate.global.currentDocId {
            view.1.alpha = 1
            view.1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            webView.addSubview(view.1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding subviews to a WKWebView? Can you not achieve the same effect by adding the content to the superview?

Comment: Take a look to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller

Comment: That sounds good.  But unsure how to add the content from dictionary to superview?

Comment: I don't know your view hierarchy but I'd assume you could do `self.view.addSubview(view.1)`.

Comment: Agree that self.view.addSubview(view.1) is ok too.  However, in either case, we are still left with the original problem: The memory used by addSubview is not being released, when the UIViewController is popped off the stack.